# Receiving data messages from com.google.cast.media namespace on Android sender app

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I created a custom receiver for Chromecast that plays video and I am trying to send messages back to my Android sender app on the same namespace. I'm currently doing it this way in Javascript:

```
window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
window.castReceiverManager.start();

//use namespace urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media to communicate to VideoCastManager in Android...?
window.customMessageBus = castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus('urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media', cast.receiver.CastMessageBus.MessageType.JSON);

//overwrite the onMessage function
var defaultFunction = window.customMessageBus.onMessage;
window.customMessageBus.onMessage = function(event) {
  window.senderId = event.senderId;
  window.message = event.data;
  defaultFunction(event);
};

//send message
window.customMessageBus.send(window.senderId, {message: "test"});
```

In Android, I am trying to receive the messages in this way:

```
mCastConsumer = new VideoCastConsumerImpl() {
        //removed all the other override functions to save space

        @Override
        public void onDataMessageReceived(String message) {
            System.out.println("CAST RECEIVED MESSAGE:" + message);
        }

    };
```

This doesn't work, and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a custom namespace not the Media namespace.

Comment: So would I have to instantiate a DataCastConsumer alongside my VideoCastConsumer to handle messages on two namespaces? I just hoped it would be possible to combine

Comment: No, VideoCastManager can provide a custom namespace as well; when you initialize it, you can specify a custom namespace and use that for communication purposes (see CCL's documentation). Since it is a custom namespace, you need to handle the receiver side yourself.